# prove that $\det(ABC) = \det(A) \det(B) \det(C)$ [for any $n×n$ matrices $A$, $B$, and $C$].

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I'm trying to write a proof for the following problem, but my proof is not strong.
Assuming the law, det(AB) = det(A) det(B)[for any n×n matrices A and B, prove that det(ABC) = det(A) det(B) det(C)[for any n×n matrices A, B, and C].

How would I go about solving this problem? I was thinking about trying to argue because the numbers of a given matrix multiply as scalars, the determinant is the product of them all and because the order of the multiplication of det(ABC) stays the same, det(ABC) = det(A) det(B) det(C) holds true. 
However, I don't think is a good enough proof and would greatly appreciate some insight.

Comment: Hint. You are overthinking this. Both matrix multiplication  and ordinary multiplication are associative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply
$$\det(ABC)=\det(AB\cdot C)=\det(AB)\det(C)=\det(A)\det(B)\det(C).$$
Note that the order in which we write the terms $\det(A),\det(B),\det(C)$ doesn't matter since these are just real numbers, and multiplication of real numbers is commutative.

Comment: Where do the reals come from? This holds in a way more general setting over arbitrary fields. Moreover I am sure you mean associative instead of commutative, right?

Comment: @PrudiiArca I was assuming the question works over $\mathbb R$, since that's the most basic context in which one first encounters matrices and determinants. You're right of course that the statement holds over arbitrary fields. And no, I don't mean associative, commutativity is right.

Comment: Oh right. I misunderstood you were talking about the order of which term you expand first (which should be associativity) but you are right aswell...